# React native FlatList Scroll item Animation start from bottom

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-hooks, jquery-animate

[FlatList Item scroll animation start Top to Bottom and Bottom to Top. Click me for to animation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpyfL.jpg)

There are two FlatList Scroll Item Animation First work when item reached almost top(Item Height) of the mobile and Second will start from bottom when Item appear

First Animation Code

```
const ItemComponent = ({item, index, scrollY}) =>{

    const ITEM_SIZE = 134+30;
        const inputRange = [-1 ,0,ITEM_SIZE * (index), ITEM_SIZE * (index+2)]
        
          const scale = scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange:[1,1,1, 0],
            extrapolate: "clamp",
          })
    return (
        <Animated.View style={[styles.overlayView, {transform:[{scale}]}]}>
        <View>.........</View>
        </Animated.View>
        )
}

export default ItemComponent;
```

Second Animation is not working Anyone have any Idea How it will work?